# Unable to use yarn and import mapbox into typescript

Tags: typescript, mapbox

I use

> yarn add --dev @types/mapbox-gl @types/geojson

to add mapbox and geojson to my project. The packages install successfully and are visible when I try to import mapboxgl.

The I build something that looks like this:

```
import * as L from 'mapbox-gl';

export class MapBuilder
{

    build(): void {
        let map = new L.Map({
            container: 'mapContainer',
            style: this.map.getStyle()
            //etc
        });
    }
}
```

When I use yarn build I get this message:

> This dependency was not found:
>
> - mapbox-gl in ./assets/js/MapBuilder.ts

Comment: From you current code snippet you are only adding @types repos, not the actual lib itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Zhonk who commented on this issue the problem is solved.

I simply forgot to add the mapbox-gl library.

> yarn add --dev mapbox-gl